# I have an Issue with "Use Product Image for Swatch if Possible" in magento 2.2

Tags: color-swatches, magento2.2.4, image-preview

I have an issue with **swatch image URL** on product detail page. You can check this [link](http://bunkbedscanada.aliansoftware.net/erika-running-short.html) for color attribute.

**Swatch Image url is :** `

> pub/media/catalog/product\cache\f307e558402b572df42bba27be68d88b//f/_/f_pillow_clr3.png

The image exists in pub media folder but it's not showing in the box.

http://prntscr.com/jrfjob

Please help I am stuck from last 2 days in this issue.

Comment: where I rename manually in background 
pub/media/catalog/product\cache\f307e558402b572df42bba27be68d88b//f/_/f_pillow_clr3.png  to pub/media/catalog/product/cache/f307e558402b572df42bba27be68d88b/f/_/f_pillow_clr3.png then its showing correctly.

Comment: I can not see the image in color swatch.

Comment: Hi @SalimKureshi, Did you somehow manage to resolve this issue? I am also facing it :(